# Delete time zone entry in Calendar's list

Tags: calendar

How can I delete an item from the Time Zone list on Calendar app?
I'm on Yosemite.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish by deleting this list?  What problem are you facing?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here (without already making assumptions about the cause)?

Comment: I had extra time zones in the list, I had accidentally selected, that I don't wish to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.iCal 'RecentlyUsedTimeZones'
```

removes all recently used time zones.
(Close Calendar app beforehand.)

I'm pretty sure (but please, someone prove me wrong) the `defaults` command can not delete single values within keys.

If you have Xcode installed, you can open the Calendar/iCal preferences file located under `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist`

You then search for the `RecentlyUsedTimeZones` key and manually delete the unwanted items within the key by clicking the (-) icon next to the item number.

[image: Xcode plist key]